# jQuery inside function calling not working

Tags: jquery, html

How can I call search function? lot's of code written outside search function so I want to execute all code How can I do this please help me.

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
        function search(){
            alert("Hello World");
    }
})
```

HTML Code:

```
<select onchange="search();">
    <option value="1">Hello</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You've asked this same question three times now, and had the same answer each time

Answer (score 6):

Any functions you call from `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers must be global functions. That's one of the many reasons not to use them. Your `search` isn't global, it's nicely contained within your `ready` handler. Which is good, globals are a Bad Thing™.

Hook up the function within your `ready` callback. Any selector for the `select` element will do; here's an example using an ID, but it doesn't have to be an ID:

```html
<select id="the-select">
    <option value="1">Hello</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $("#the-select").on("change", search);
    function search(){
            alert("Hello World");
    }
})
```

If you don't call `search` from any other code, you can combine that:

```
$(function(){
    $("#the-select").on("change", function search(){
    // Name here is optional --------------^--- but handy for debugging
    // if an error is thrown in the function
        alert("Hello World");
    });
})
```